# What changes did Oscar Hammerstein make to P.G. Wodehouse's lyrics for the Jerome Kern tune Bill?

Tags: lyrics, musicals

What changes did Oscar Hammerstein II make to P.G. Wodehouse's lyrics for the Jerome Kern tune Bill?

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bill_(song)) :

> "Bill" is a song heard in Act II of Kern and Hammerstein's classic 1927 musical, Show Boat. The song was written by Kern and P. G. Wodehouse for their 1917 musical Oh, Lady! Lady!! for Vivienne Segal to perform, but it was withdrawn because it was considered too melancholy for that show. When Kern and Hammerstein were at work on a serious and somewhat tragic production of Show Boat, however, they decided that the song would be perfect for a nightclub scene in that show. Hammerstein revised Wodehouse's original lyrics somewhat (although he would always give full credit to Wodehouse for the song and take none for himself), and the song was given to real-life nightclub singer Helen Morgan to sing as she portrayed the mulatto Julie in that version of Show Boat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Change 1

In the Wodehouse original, the lyrics

> But along came Bill, whose quite the opposite
> of all the men in storybooks
> in grace and looks
> I know that Apollo
> would beat him all Hollow

in the Hammerstein version becomes

> But along came Bill, whose not the type at all
> you'd meet him on the street and never notice him
> His form and face,
> his manly grace,
> are not the kind you would find in a statue

#### Change 2

Later in the song, Wodehouse wrote

> He's just my Bill
> He has no gifts at all
> A motorcar he cannot steer
> And it seems clear
> Whenever he dances
> His partner takes chances

which Hammerstein changed to

> He's just my Bill
> An ordinary guy
> He hasn't got a thing that I can brag about
> And yet to be upon his knee
> So comfy and roomy — feels natural to me.

#### Research recordings

Here is the Wodehouse version, sung by Lara Cazalet with pianist Steven Blier.

And the Hammerstein version is sung in this recording by Rebecca Trehearn with accompaniment by musicians of the New London Theatre's 2016 production of *Show Boat!*

#### Other differences (in the recordings)

There are two other trivial changes, which may be due to the singers themselves:

**Difference 1**

> Like the heroes bold in the books I read

becomes

> ... in the books I've read

and

**Difference 2**

> and I can't explain why he should be

becomes

> Oh, I can't explain ...

Comment: There is also a change at 1:28  Wodehouse: "Because he's just OK"" becomes Hammerstein: 1:38 "Because he's just so Bill" (which in other versions like Artie Shaw/Helen Forrest is "Because he's just my Bill".

Comment: As I mention in https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mpH8fohNP30 Helen Forrest sings at 1:06

Are not the KIND
that you would FIND
in a statue

But  phrasing suggested in the Hammerstein lyrics suggest another stress and rhyme:

Are not the kind  THAT you 
would find in a STATue

For a rendition of that listen to https://youtu.be/eQmsCUHSxqc?si=oE2piuQUH6VpOAgM&t=73 or  https://youtu.be/dDwPhfN-wCM?si=J2lQYGAsamtJQmsY&t=67. 

The latter comes the closest to trying to get both rhymes in there

Comment: However even better go get both rhymes is https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_H48C_xf8HE where "statue" is changed to "Chris Matthews".